# Python bittrex several markets

Tags: python, python-requests

I work with API bittrex. I get Bid value for chosen market. This code work pretty well for one market.

```
import requests
import time


def get_current_Bid(managed_currency, money_currency, session):
    url = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker'
    req = requests.Request('GET', url, data={'market': money_currency + '-' + managed_currency})
    prepped = session.prepare_request(req)
    resp = session.send(prepped)
    try:
        return float(resp.json()['result']['Bid'])
    except TypeError:
        print('Error, try get_current_Bid in 1 sec.')
        return get_current_Bid(managed_currency, money_currency, session)


session = requests.Session()

while True:
    bid1 = get_current_Bid('OMG', 'BTC', session)
    print(bid1,'OMG-BTC')
```

I get the output:

0.00130001 OMG-BTC 
0.00130001 OMG-BTC 
0.00130001 OMG-BTC 
0.00130001 OMG-BTC 
0.00130001 OMG-BTC 
0.00130001 OMG-BTC 
0.00130001 OMG-BTC

OK. It is real current Bid for OMG-BTC.
But if I want work with 2 markets or more, I have very strange result. Slightly changed the code to work with two markets.

```
while True:
    bid1 = get_current_Bid('OMG', 'BTC', session)
    print(bid1,'OMG-BTC')
    bid2 = get_current_Bid('BTC', 'USDT', session)
    print(bid2, 'BTC-USDT')
```

And I have this output:

0.00127796 OMG-BTC 
0.00127796 BTC-USDT 
0.00127796 OMG-BTC 
5800.00000001 BTC-USDT 
5800.00000001 OMG-BTC 
5800.00000001 BTC-USDT 
5800.00000001 OMG-BTC 
5800.00000001 BTC-USDT

As you can see *0.00127796* is prise for *OMG-BTC*, **not** for *BTC-USDT*

And *5800.00000001* is prise for *BTC-USDT*, **not** for *OMG-BTC*

But in output this prises as if they intersect. Sometimes the price of another currency is given for one currency. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be with the frequency of the requests to the API.  If I put a 5-second time delay between requests, the values come out different each time (as expected):

```
while True:
    bid1 = get_current_Bid('OMG', 'BTC', session)
    print(bid1,'OMG-BTC')
    time.sleep(5)
    bid2 = get_current_Bid('BTC', 'USDT', session)
    print(bid2, 'BTC-USDT')
    time.sleep(5)
```

gives me the output:

(0.00117711, 'OMG-BTC')
(6087.0, 'BTC-USDT')
(0.00117613, 'OMG-BTC')
(6087.0, 'BTC-USDT')
(0.00117613, 'OMG-BTC')
(6087.0, 'BTC-USDT')

I'm not sure you're doing anything wrong, but rather the API has trouble keeping up with the requests (which seems like a bug because the *success* entry still comes back True).  You might want to file this with Bittrex's support, as I can't find anything in the API documentation about what frequency of requests is supported.